# Render a ListView.ListTile in a StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter, listview, stream-builder

I have a Flutter app where I am trying to render a ListTile inside a StreamBuilder.

I am having this error when loading the app:

> type 'Future<List>' is not a subtype of type 'List'

The neabyComp() function snippet:

```
Stream nearbyComp() async* {
    var pos = await location.getLocation();

    GeoFirePoint point =
        geo.point(latitude: pos.latitude, longitude: pos.longitude);
    final CollectionReference users =
        _firebaseFirestore.collection("Companies");

    double radius = 10;
    String field = 'location';

    Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>> stream = geo
        .collection(collectionRef: users)
        .within(center: point, radius: radius, field: field, strictMode: true);

    yield stream;
  }
```

This is the snippet of code of the StreamBuilder where the error is coming from:

```
Container(
            child: StreamBuilder(
              stream: nearbyComp(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text('Something went wrong');
                }
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return Text("Loading");
                }
                return Container(
                  child: new ListView(
                    children: snapshot.data.map((document) {
                      // Adding snapshot.data.map<Widget> also returns error "Future<List<Widget>> is not a subtype of type List<Widget>"
                      return new ListTile(
                        title: new Text(document['companyName']),
                        subtitle: new Image.network(document['url']),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: you should try listView.builder, it will accept Future Lists

Comment: @pskink write on the line with the comment, children: snapshot.data.map((document)...

Comment: @MehranUllah Oh, interesting, I will try it then, and let you know if it worked, thanks

Comment: add `print(snapshot);` in the first line of your `builder:`, what do you see on the logs?

Comment: @pskink The only thing that shows up is `AsyncSnapshot<dynamic>(ConnectionState.waiting, null, null, null)`

Comment: And `AsyncSnapshot<dynamic>(ConnectionState.done, Instance of '_AsBroadcastStream<List<DocumentSnapshot>>', null, null)`

Comment: @pskink I think you removed your comment, but it actually changed the error to `type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Widget>'`, I think we are getting closer

Comment: `snapshot.data.map` -> `snapshot.data.map<Widget>`

Comment: Yeah mate! Just fixed it and it worked. Thank you so much, I spent literally 2 months on this problem, and it was a basic *, can you comment the answer bellow so I can vote it?

Comment: 2 months??? you mean 2 days? anyway, feel free to post a self answer if you want

Comment: No, 2 months haha, I've being going round and round with different approaches to this feature, but I am really new to this stuff specially flutter, and could not find a good answer to it. And now you solved, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone comes to this problem, here is the solution provided by @pskink (Look for the comments on the code snippets):

```
Stream nearbyComp() async* {
    var pos = await location.getLocation();

    GeoFirePoint point =
        geo.point(latitude: pos.latitude, longitude: pos.longitude);
    final CollectionReference users =
        _firebaseFirestore.collection("Companies");

    double radius = 10;
    String field = 'location';

    Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>> stream = geo
        .collection(collectionRef: users)
        .within(center: point, radius: radius, field: field, strictMode: true);

    yield* stream; // In this line, add the * after yield
  }
```

And the other part is here:

```
Container(
            child: StreamBuilder(
              stream: nearbyComp(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text('Something went wrong');
                }
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return Text("Loading");
                }
                return Container(
                  child: new ListView(
                    children: snapshot.data.map((document) {
                      // Add snapshot.data.map<Widget> 
                      return new ListTile(
                        title: new Text(document['companyName']),
                        subtitle: new Image.network(document['url']),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
```